Inverse of matrix on increasing dimension (number of rows) by one.
Given an invertible matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, we make another matrix $B\in \mathbb{C}^{(n+1)\times (n+1)}$ from $A$ by adding a row to the bottom and a column to the right. That is,
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} A & c\\
c^\dagger & b \end{bmatrix},$$
where $c$ is a column $\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times 1}$, and $c^\dagger$ is its Hermitian conjugate. $b\in \mathbb{C}$.
We know that $B$ is invertible. How do we obtain the inverse of $B$ in terms of $A^{-1}$?
